# How to not call didChangeDependencies() after pressing back button from child widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a provider package to load products in an array by calling `didChangeDependencies()` method. This is working fine even when there is some change due to filters and new products are fetched then with the help of `notifyListeners()` this page rebuilds successfully. Although the problem arises when I tap on the product card to see product details screen and comes back to the all products screen, then didChangeDependencies is called again and whole page refreshes. Is there any way by which I can stop triggering `didChangeDependencies()` when I get back to this page or there is any other better way to implement what I am doing here?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'loader.dart';
import '../screens/product_overview.dart';
import '../providers/user.dart';

class AllProducts extends StatefulWidget {
  final double deviceHeight;
  final double deviceWidth;
  AllProducts(this.deviceHeight, this.deviceWidth);
  @override
  _AllProductsState createState() => _AllProductsState();
}

class _AllProductsState extends State<AllProducts> {
  List _products = [];
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool _gettingMoreProducts = false;

  _loadMoreProducts() async {
    print('Reached end of list');
    if (_gettingMoreProducts) {
      print('Already getting products');
      return;
    }
    print('Firestore function called');
    _gettingMoreProducts = true;
    dynamic newProducts =
        await Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).getProducts();
    _products.addAll(newProducts);
    setState(() {});
    print('New Products added');
    _gettingMoreProducts = false;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    print('Getting new products from init state');
    Provider.of<User>(context).getProducts().then((products) {
      setState(() {
        _products = products;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
        height: widget.deviceHeight * 0.80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: _isLoading
            ? Loader()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _products.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // if (index == _products.length - 1) {
                  //   _loadMoreProducts();
                  // }
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      setState(() {
                        _products.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                    background: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    secondaryBackground: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      // Product Overview builds a simple card for product and whenever I tap on card it moves to product detail screen which is just a simple screen with product details and when I press back button from that page all products rebuild again due to didchangedependencies.
                      child: ProductOverview(_products[index],
                          widget.deviceHeight, widget.deviceWidth),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try upgrade to flutter SDK >= Beta v1.14.6. Team Flutter is fixed it on this release.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/49527

Comment: In Flutter 1.20.1 I still have this issue. The `didChangeDependencies` is called on a route widget when I press Back.

Comment: Ah, my issue is different, I'm getting notifications because of ModalRoute subscription: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63364

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin, OMG, Aleksander you saved me! :) I spent days and didn't understand why popped route calls `didChangeDependencies` and therefore redundant `build`. I removed subscription to navigator observer and now all works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool firstTime = true;
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your code would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is, inside `didChangeDependencies` check if your old products are the same as the new value for provider, if they are then don't assign them to your `_products`